# restore form data after validation error in jsf

Tags: jsf

I have a combo box(drop down list) and a text field on the page. Both of them has required set to true. When I select a value in the drop down and submit the form, the validation kicks in and I'm redirected to the same page since the text field value is null. Which is good but I loose the data selected in the drop down list. How can I retain the form data when there is a validation error? I'm using facelets with jsf1.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HI,

It is working fine in JSF 2.0. I have just tried it. I have written the following code:

```
 <f:view>
        <h:form>
            <h:inputText id="name" value="#{jsfBean.name }" required="true"/>
            <h:selectOneMenu id="items" value="#{jsfBean.selectedItem }" required="true">
                <f:selectItems value="#{jsfBean.items }"/>
            </h:selectOneMenu>
            <h:commandButton id="submit" value="Submit" action="#{jsfBean.submit }" />
        </h:form>
    </f:view>

private String selectedItem;
private ArrayList<SelectItem> items = null;
public String getSelectedItem() {
    this.selectedItem = "--Select--";
    return selectedItem;
}
public void setSelectedItem(String selectedItem) {      
    this.selectedItem = selectedItem;
}
public ArrayList<SelectItem> getItems() {
    this.items = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();
    SelectItem selectItem = new SelectItem("1","1");
    SelectItem selectItem1 = new SelectItem("--Select--","--Select--");
    this.items.add(selectItem);
    this.items.add(selectItem1);
    return items;
}
public void setItems(ArrayList<SelectItem> items) {
    this.items = items;
}
```

Comment: It is working in JSF 1.2 also. Once I have read in the article saying there is some bug in SelectMenu to retain the value. Can you update to the latest version 1.2.X and try it.